# How to read text file from assets folder with expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I created an project with expo, and I'm trying to read txt file in assets folder, but i got error: `Unable to resolve "./assets/a.txt" from "App.tsx"`,I ensure my path is correct

My Code:

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar"
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native"
import { Asset } from "expo-asset"

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const asset = Asset.fromModule(require("./assets/a.txt"))
    console.log("file path:", asset.localUri)
  }, [])

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Open up App.tsx to start working on your app!</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

reproduce repo: https://github.com/wang-hang/expo-demo

Comment: I solved the problem by reading the doc: 
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/customizing-metro/#adding-more-file-extensions-to-assetexts

Answer (score 0):

File structure looks good to me. It should work.

If it isn't, what Expo version are you using? If it is latest stable version i.e. 49, why not try and use *useAssets* hook?

```
const [assets, error] = useAssets([require('./assets/a.txt'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was able to solve the problem by reading this document.